# beta reduction on type

Tags: haskell, lambda

When translate the `(+)` operator into lambda calculus, then it would look like:

```
λx.λy.x + y
```

then do beta reduction

```
(λx.λy.x + y) 1 --substitute x through 1
(λy.1 + y)      
(λy.1 + y)    2 --substitute y through 2
1 + 2
3               --is the normal form
```

Now, I have a function with following type signature:

```
f :: (t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t
```

My questions are:

- Can I translate the type signature of function `f` into lambda
  calculus(Like I translate the + operator above)?
- Can I apply beta reduction principle for type too(know as type
  substitution)?

With type substitution, I mean as follow:

```
*Twinplicative> :t id (+)
id (+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

I did substitute the first parameter of `id`, know as `a`, with the type signature of `(+)` operator, then it becomes to `Num a => a -> a -> a`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function the same way as you use a value in lambda calculus. Your example with the `(+)` would look like this:

```
(λf. λx. λy. f x y) (+) 1 2
~> (λx. λy. (+) x y)  1 2
~> (λy. (+) 1 y) 2
~> ((+) 1 2)
~> 1 + 2
~> 3
```

You can substitute your known types, but there to ensure correctness you would have to run the function and see if the types match.

However, in pure lambda calculus you can't encode the type signature, that's what [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) or [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) is for. This allows type annotations and you can use a type inference algorithm to check on *compile time* if everything matches. It narrows the rules for beta reduction by enforcing type substitutions.

A more complete introduction and example code for a type inference algorithm can be found [here](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/006_hindley_milner.html).